# LibGDX HexagonalTiledMapRenderer wrong stagger index?

Tags: libgdx, tiled

Im using Tiled map editor, Hexagonal(staggered) map, libgdx version `1.9.9`

If I set `staggeredIndex = even` in tiled map editor, libgdx seems to render `odd`

If I set it to `odd` in map editor, libgdx renders `even`

**Screen Shots:**
[image]
[image]

Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void create () {
    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("mapa.tmx");
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()); 
    mapRenderer = new HexagonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cam.update();
    mapRenderer.setView(cam);
    mapRenderer.render();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I found the problem ima go ahead an answer my own question.

The tile(0,0) in Tiled is in top-left corner while in libgdx tile(0,0) is down-left corner.

This is why staggeredY axis causes problem in a map where the height is even like 10 tiles, in the map editor the first row is `even` and the last row is `odd` in libgdx the last row is actually the first row, so its `even`.

Solution:
Make the map height odd, instead of 10 tiles I made it 11.
You could make small changes to `HexagonalTiledMapRenderer` like

```
if(mapHeight % 2 === 0)
  staggerIndex = !staggerIndex
```

I just didn't mind adding an extra row.

I personally think they should correct this in libgdx